# NSString normalization using NFD unicode

Tags: objective-c, iphone, unicode, nsstring, unicode-normalization

In my application I have to normalize an NSString using NFD Unicode system. How can I do this? I need to convert a string which the user entered as normalized and from this normalized string, I have to calculate a number. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSString *nfdString = [yourString decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping];
```